# ReactJS | Getting data from URL returns null

Tags: reactjs

I am sending a form data from a form in reactjs. Some pre inputs from the user have to be sent altogether with the form. I get that data from the URL of the parent file and the form is in the child component.

Parent url: http://localhost:3000/uploadlist?phmcy=2

I have to get the phmcy value from the URL. (Here the data have to be passed is '2').

But the phamcy value returns "null" And I tried everything I knew but it keeps returning the null value.

The code segment of the parent file:

```
import Upload from './Upload'
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';

export default function Uploadlist() {
    let myphmcy = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get("phmcy.value")    
    console.log(myphmcy);
//rest of the code is not added.
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Upload from './Upload'
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Uploadlist() {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    const phmcy = new URLSearchParams(search).get("phmcy");
    console.log(phmcy);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that! but it returns space in the console.

Comment: @DevindiSiwurathna Can you please check my updated answer!

Comment: it also remains undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, I think you are trying to get the `value` inside `phmcy`, right?

Change the `get` state meant to the following:

```js
let myphmcy = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get("phmcy").value
```

Comment: Can you please try it without `value` and let me know the output of `console.log`

Comment: I tried that too. with that, it shows nothing in the console. (it returns just a space only)

Comment: You can try parsing it using JSON.parse. I suspect it's a string that we are receiving. `String.value` is expected to return `undefined`.

Comment: It is a int value.